# Is there an option to get notifications when a meeting starts in Google Classroom?

Tags: google-classroom

I'm always late because I can't join until the teacher starts the meeting, but I don't know when does the teacher starts the meeting. Is it possible to get a push notification when it starts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Classroom does not include notifications for meetings. [Here](https://support.google.com/edu/classroom/answer/6141557?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en#zippy=%2Ccustomize-notifications%2Cturn-all-notifications-on-or-off-for-a-class%2Cread-notifications) is a list of all the possible notifications you can get with Google Classroom.

Moreover, Meet does not include either the [type of notification](https://support.google.com/meet/answer/7353922?hl=en) you are looking for.

#### Workarounds

Instead, if the meeting created also creates an event in your calendar, you can take advantage of [event reminders](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/6285327?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) to send you an email just right before the event starts.

Comment: Thank you... Sad that Microsoft and Zoom could make it, but Google can't ://